# Please help me with this partial derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

$z=f(u,v)$  ; $u=x^2 + y^2$  and $v=2xy $

FIND $(∂z/∂x)^2 + (∂z/∂y)^2$

Now, i am confused on how to differentiate z, (do i diffrentiate u and v both or what)...please help me with the procedure!.

Comment: Please help him with downvote so, that he can write post in proper context .

Comment: You can just search for information and come up with http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChainRule.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

$$z'_x:=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=f'_uu'_x+f'_vv'_x\;,\;\;z''_{x^2}=f''_{u^2}u'_x+f'_uu''_{x^2}+f''_{v^2}v'_x+f'_vv''_{x^2}$$

Try to complete the question now.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer.
Can you help me with the $f′_u$ part.

Comment: @ICEburger You're welcome, but I can't help you with that since we're *not given* what $\;f\;$ is...